# Why do we need salt bridge in a cell during potentiometric measurement as there is no or minimum redox activity at electrodes?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

In electrochemical cell, we need salt bridge to maintain electrical neutrility in both halves cells during redox reaction?. But in during potentiometric measurement, no or minimum current is drawn and redix activity at electrode is negligible then why do still need salt bridge in this case?

Comment: Still you do not want change in potential due to resistance and you do need a full circiut. Recall Ohm's law V=IR.

Comment: Then how does salt bridge help to minimize this resistance as it's function is only to minimize junction potential and maintain electrical neutrility??